# What's the usage of で in this sentence: 日本はユーラシア大陸の東にある島国で国の70%は山です。

Tags: grammar, copula

> 日本はユーラシア大陸の東にある島国**で**国の70%は山です。

I translated it as something like "Japan is an island country of east of the Eurasia continent and 70% of it is made of mountains."

Answer (score 6):

> 日本はユーラシア大陸の東にある島国**で**国の70%は山です。

The で is the continuative form of the copula だ. Your translation looks good to me. You can split the sentence into two, like this:

> 日本はユーラシア大陸の東にある島国 **だ/です**。（そして）国の70%は山です。

"Japan is an island country located to the east of the Eurasian Continent. (And) 70% of the land is mountains."